# Get (x,y) coordinates of an obstacle from a map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I need help,

Can someone tell me how to get the (x,y) coordinates of an obstacle from a 2d map created with gmapping.

I'm working with a Turtlebot robot, ROS Fuerte in Ubuntu.

After retrieving the position ((x,y) coordinates), can we remove the obstacle from the map.

Is it possible to add an obstacle to a created map in a specified position ? if yes How ?

any help is appreciated !

waiting for your answers :)

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201172/get-(x,y)-coordinates-of-an-obstacle-from-a-map/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo avicenna,

actually in occupancy grid maps like in gmapping you dont speak of (x,y) coordinates you are speaking of cells. Of course you can assume that the middlepoint of a cell are you coordinates.

So the Occoupancy Grid map is defined [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) but the most important is:

> The map data, in row-major order, starting with (0,0).  Occupancy probabilities are in the range [0,100].  Unknown is -1.

GMapping follows a maximum likelihood convention where a occupancy grid map is a Tri-State:

-1: Unknow

0: Free

100: Occupied

So what you need actually to do is iterating over the cells, check if the probability is 100 and if so print the location:

```
    for (int width=0; width < occupancy_grid->info.width; ++width)
    {
        for (int height=0; height < occupancy_grid->info.height; ++height)
        {
            if(occupancy_grid->data[height*occupancy_grid.info.width + width] > 0)
            {
               x = width * occupancy_grid->info.resolution + occupancy_grid->info.resolution / 2;
               y = height * occupancy_grid->info.resolution + occupancy_grid->info.resolution / 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Be careful with is code! I write it out of my memory and its not optimized, with datatypes or even correct. Just an illustration how you can do it.  occupancy_grid is here a pointer to a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid Object.

The code also assumes that your (x,y)-origin is at (0,0). When its not you have to add it to x and y.

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avicenna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29922/avicenna/) on 2017-05-23**:
thanks chwimmer. I understand now. Also thanks for code sample :)